# How to convert NSString "{265, 188}" to {265, 188}

Tags: objective-c

I have a `NSString` variable that contains **"{265, 188}"**. I want just **{265, 188}** in a variable. What should I do?

**Edit:**

The code so far is:

```
//This I get from some XML so I change this part
NSDictionary* controlConditions =@{@"NSPosition":@"{265, 188}"}; 

NSString* a=(NSString*)[controlConditions valueForKey:@"AXPosition"];
```

After all, I need to send this to apple script set `_controlid_` to `a(variable)` where i require it to be **{265, 188}**

**Edit:**
The variable `controlConditions` is taken from an XML that gives the position of a UIelement. The NSDictionary returns **"{265, 188}"** in `a(variable)`. I need to send **{265, 188}** to an Applescript to match it to the position of various UIelements to get the right one. Hope this makes the problem clearer.

Comment: What sort of variable? Array, list, packed integer?

Comment: Show us your code you've with which you've tried to solved the problem so far.

Comment: @paxdiablo that's what i want to know what kind of variable should I use for this. For me any of them will work.

Comment: @bish The is not direct but here it is

Comment: I guess value of `a` is correct but it depends how do you send it to script. Can you please show us ? IMHO, it should be a `NSSString`.

Comment: How are you displaying this value, where you see the quotes?  The above assignment statement will not produce a value which is actually enclosed in quotes, though you will see quotes if you NSLog the dictionary.

Comment: (And if you really want to know how to remove the quotes (if they're really there), **READ THE DOCUMENTATION** for NSString.)

Comment: @HotLicks the quotes are there when I pass the value of this variable to my applescript and I don't get the desired results.

Comment: @HotLicks As for the documentation of NSString, It doesn't help remove the quotes anyhow

Comment: So how did the quotes get there?  The above code will not put quotes there.  (And you apparently haven't actually read the NSString documentation if you say it won't remove the quotes.)

Comment: @HotLicks Please just tell me a solution, I have a lot of work right now and close deadlines.. And as for the quotes, the code only puts it there. I obviously didn't put them there

Comment: In order to help you we'd need you to actually provide some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSString *value = @"{265, 188}";        
    CGFloat x, y;
    sscanf([value UTF8String], "{%lf, %lf}", &x, &y);       
    NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(x,y);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromPoint(point));
```

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you just put the values into a fixed array:

```
int anIntArray[2] = {265,188};
NSLog(@"anIntArray = %d, %d", anIntArray[0], anIntArray[1]);
```

prints:

```
anIntArray = 265, 188
```

Maybe you want to use some type other than int.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really not clear. However, a string of the form `{265, 188}` is very possibly the result of a previous call to `NSStringFromPoint()` on an `NSPoint` whose `x` field is 265 and `y` field is 188.

Do you perhaps want to get the `NSPoint` value back out of the string? If so, you would pass the string to `NSPointFromString()`.

That would not explain how quote characters actually got into the original string, if they are really there. (Unexpectedly, `NSPointFromString()` actually does still work with a string which contains quote characters.)

Comment: I got the variable from an XML that gives the position of a uielement. Now I want to send this value {265, 188} to an applescript to match the position of each uielement with this value and the correct uielement. Applescript however takes position without quotes but the input from XML is string so it has quotes

Comment: Also the XML data is stored in an NSDictionary variable so it has all values in quotes. If that helps understand a little more @Ken Thomases